# How to create a compound index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a requirement in which I need to create a compound index name  `advisor_name` on the `Employee` table

```
where Advisor Name = Last_Name + ", " + First_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add persisted computed column and than create index on it.
For more information: [Indexes on Computed Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.EmployeeTable
ADD AdvisorName AS Last_Name + ', ' + First_Name PERSISTED
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_EmployeeTable_AdvisorName ON dbo.EmployeeTable
(AdvisorName)
```